# Can't pickle <java class 'java.lang.Integer'> in python

Tags: python, pickle, jpype, jaydebeapi

I'm fetching data from a db with the use of `jaydebeapi` pkg. I want to serialize the data (it's in list of tuples format) using `pickle`.

The data may contain different java class types. For a certain data type (`<java class 'java.lang.Integer'>`) I get the following error message:

```
PicklingError: Can't pickle <java class 'java.lang.Integer'>: it's not found as java.lang.java.lang.Integer
```

Is there any way to fix this? Or is there any known workaround?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Could you add (an excerpt) of your implementation? It looks strange to me that it searches for `java.lang.java.lang.Integer`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the [JPype Pickle Module](https://jpype.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#jpype-pickle-module) instead of pickle.

```
from jpype.pickle import JPickler
```

From the docs:

> Mixed pickle files containing both Java and Python objects are allowed.